# Navigation pushview Controller is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am implement the TabBar app for ipad & iphone both. But In IPAD the navigation controller is not working for ipad nib in table cell. The viewdid Load method is not call for ipad.
But it work fine for iphone..
self.navigationController is NULL for ipad only in my class to navigate.
Help me!!

my code is as follow:

```
//Connet.m:

if(i==1)
{
    TwitterController *tc;
    if ([self isPad]) {
    tc = [[TwitterController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterController_ipad" bundle:nil];    
}
else
    tc = [[TwitterController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tc animated:YES];        
NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);   /Problem ****NULL*****///////          


//TWITTER.m    
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            //Custom initialization
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;          
        }
    return self;
}  

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    NSString *urlAddress = @"https://twitter.com/UJUDGEIT1";
    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    //URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];   
    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webv loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    NSString *nibname=@"";
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){

        nibname=@"TwitterController_ipad";   
    }
    else{
        nibname=@"TwitterController"; 


    }
    TwitterController *view = [[TwitterController alloc] initWithNibName:nibname bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Write this code in your app delegate class.  The `viewDidLoad` method gets called.

Comment: But all are navigationController are working.  Only in my this class ,it is not working..

Comment: I implementing TabBar Application

Answer (score 0):

piyush

how you implement your tab bar.
make each controller of  tab bar   as navigation controller. it may called your view did load method.

following code may help you. it create 2 controller on tab bar. finally at it to root view controller.

```
-(void)createTabbar{
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        //Controller 1
        PasswordVC *pvc = [[PasswordVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PasswordVC" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *passwordNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pvc];
        passwordNav.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
        [controllers addObject:passwordNav];
        pvc.title = @"Password";
        [pvc release];

        [passwordNav release];

        //Controller 2
        SettingVC *SVC = [[SettingVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingVC" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *settingNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:SVC];
        settingNav.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
        [controllers addObject:settingNav];
        SVC.title = @"Settings";
        [SVC release];

        [settingNav release];    
    }
    else {         //ipad

    }

    _tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    _tabBarController.delegate=self;
    _tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
    _tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = controllers;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:_window cache:NO];
    _window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: see my code I got NULL for self.navegationController in coonect.m BUT ONLY for IPAD . the app is work fine for iphone..